# Ignore an entire directory when using File::Find in Perl script

Tags: perl, filesystems

I have a script which scans every local filesystem for world-writable files. Any found files are written to an output file. It also uses another file which provides a list of files to ignore.

We have the Tivoli monitoring agent installed which, for some strange reason, has been designed to create every file in its installation path with world-writable permissions. As it is known and there is little we can do about it, we would like to simply ignore the entire directory.

I imagine I can utilize a glob such as `/opt/IBM/ITM/*` but I haven't the first bit of a clue at to how to do that.

At the moment I've hard-coded the directory into the script. This is less than ideal, but functional. I'd prefer to have it in the list of excludes.

Over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51473/optimizing-perl-script-which-looks-for-world-writable-files/54247?noredirect=1#comment95201_54247) it was suggested that I use `File::Find::prune`. Unfortunately,  this hasn't worked. From what I gather and understand about `File::Find::prune` if it finds a file at `/opt/IBM/ITM/.../.../file.txt` which is supposed to be excluded, it will then skip the entire `/opt/IBM/ITM/.../.../` directory. This is fine, but it means I would need to have an exclusion entry for every sub-directoy of `/opt/IBM/ITM/`. This would be a tedious endeavor considering how many sub-directories and sub-sub-directories there are.

I did try placing a world-writable file under `/opt/IBM/ITM/` and add that to the exclusion list, but it didn't work. I'm guessing because it wasn't found first.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $dir = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $mtab = "/etc/mtab";
my $permFile = "world_writable_files.txt";
my $tmpFile = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $exclude = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";
my $mask = S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH;
my (%excludes, %devNums);
my $errHeader;

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

open MT, "<${mtab}" or die "Cannot open ${mtab}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]);
    my @stats = stat($line[1]);
    $devNums{$stats[0]} = undef;
  }
}

close MT;

# Build a hash from /usr/local/etc/world_writables_excludes.txt
if ((! -e $exclude) || (-z $exclude)) {
  $errHeader = <<HEADER;
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!                                                  !!
!! /usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt is    !!
!! is missing or empty. This report includes        !!
!! every world-writable file including those which  !!
!! are expected and should be excluded.             !!
!!                                                  !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


HEADER

} else {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  while (<XCLD>) {
    chomp;
    $excludes{$_} = 1;
  }
}

sub wanted {
  my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);

  # Is it excluded from the report...
  return if exists $excludes{$File::Find::name};

  # ...is the Tivoli installation directory...
  return if ($File::Find::name =~ /\b\/ITM\b/);

  # ...in a special directory, ...
  return if ($File::Find::name =~ /^\bsys\b|\bproc\b|\bdev\b$/);

  # ...a regular file, ...
  return unless -f;

  # ...local, ...
  return unless (exists $devNums{$dirStats[0]});

  # ...and world writable?
  return unless ($dirStats[2] & $mask) == $mask;

  # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files
  print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");

}

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir($dir or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${dir}, $!") unless (-d $dir);

# Create our filehandle for writing our findings
open WWFILE, ">${dir}${tmpFile}" or die "Cannot open ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";
print(WWFILE "${errHeader}") if ($errHeader);

finddepth(\&wanted, @mounts);

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${tmpFile} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${dir}${tmpFile}") {
  unlink "${dir}${tmpFile}";

} else {
  rename("${dir}${tmpFile}","${dir}${permFile}") or die "Cannot rename file ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";

}
```

It has also been suggested elsewhere that I use File::Find::Rule. I'd rather avoid doing this simply because I don't want to perform a complete rewrite of the script.

As I've said, the script above works. I'd prefer not hard-coding the exclusion, though. Figuring out how to do this would also allow me to remove the match against the "special" directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prune an entire directory tree, just set the `$File::Find::prune` value in your `wanted` sub.   This will work as long as `bydepth` was not specified:

```
if ($File::Find::name eq '/opt/IBM/ITM') {
    $File::Find::prune = 1;
    return;
}
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is that `$File::Find::prune` will only ignore a directory in which a file is found. For instance, when a file is found in `/opt/IBM/ITM/log/` `$File::Find::prune will will prevent any more files in `/opt/IBM/ITM/log/` from being processed. However, every other sub-directory under `/opt/IBM/ITM/` will continue to be processed with `$File::Find::prune` operating on each one as it is encountered.

Comment: The docs for this feature are not very explicit, but that is not my observed results.  When I use this feature it completely skips the full directory tree I specify to be pruned.

Comment: I guess I wasn't looking at it properly. It appears to work as you suggest. I went ahead and combined all of the directories I want to ignore into `if ($File:Find::name =~ m{^/sys|^/proc|^/dev|^/opt/IBM/ITM})`. It seems to return the expected results.